# Is it legal to justify a terrorist attack against the Iranian people by Iranian opposition group (or Israelis who speak Persian) in the west?

Tags: united-states, israel, terrorism, iran, opposition

According to the [NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/iran-explosions-qassem-soleimani-memorial-quds-force-us-drone-strike-rcna132039):

> Two explosions killed at least 84 people in southern Iran on Wednesday at a memorial event for a senior Iranian general killed in a 2020 U.S. drone strike, ramping up tensions in a region already on edge.
>
> The first of two blasts hit around 2,300 feet from the tomb of Gen. Qassem Soleimani in the Kerman Martyrs Cemetery, the semiofficial news agency ISNA reported. It added that the second explosion was around 2,000 feet away.
>
> No one immediately claimed responsibility for the blasts — which injured more than 210 people in one of the worst attacks in the Islamic Republic's history.

After the terrorist attack and the increase in the number of martyrs, most of the Iranian opposition groups abroad started to show their happiness about this event in social media and Radio, TV, YouTube, etc.. This is not the first time that Iranian opposition groups are happy about a terrorist attack against the Iranian people. Most of them believe those who participated in General Soleimani's ceremony are government forces or supporters of Iran's ideology and conclude that they deserved to die and we should not be saddened by their death.

Some of the most prominent of these opponents who are in **US and Canada** are:

- Ali Karimi: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/alikarimi_ak8?lang=en) and [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/aliiiiiiiikarimi8/?hl=en)
- [Iran International TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_International)

and some others. For example *Iran International TV* aired a program after the terrorist attack with this theme - *The events in Kerman are not important for the people of Iran*. After ISIS claimed responsibility for the terrorist attack, they aired another program with this question *Should we sympathize with the victims of this incident?*

Some others did not show their happiness and expressed sympathy after ISIS's statement.

**Question:** Is it legal for the Iranian opposition group or [Israelis who speak Farsi/Persian](https://www.newsweek.com/israeli-students-learn-farsi-spies-958993) (see for example this [tweet](https://twitter.com/HananyaPersian/status/1742513875143069980) - although my question is more about US and Canadian laws) to celebrate or justify a terrorist attack against the Iranian people? I know US and Israeli hostility to Iran is fierce, but does US or Canadian law allow such TV stations or people to celebrate a terrorist attack publicly?

Comment: This is a pretty poorly worded question.  From the "Isn't it" in the title, to the use of "martyrs".   But perhaps you can clarify.  Are you asking about the Law in Iran, or the Law in some other country.  It's not possible to ask if something is legal, unless you specify a country.

Comment: On that basis I'm voting to close.

Comment: I think *Israelis who speak Persian* does not really fit into the context of the question - it seems as an attempt to push a theory that Israel is behind the attack. Apart from that, in the US this is probably covered by freedom of speech, although IMHO there is little to celebrate - murder remains murder, even murder in the name of just cause. This is not unlike Palestinian kids distributing candies after a successful terrorist attack, dancing on roofs after 9/11, or the acts on Campuses, dismissing October 7 as legitimate struggle.

Comment: @RogerV. The TV I mentioned hosted an interview with Netanyahu. It also uses persian-speaking Israelis as political experts in its programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

The [First Amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-1/) requires that Congress makes no law that prevents freedom of speech or the press.  That means that a law that prevents people from expressing happiness at a terrorist attack is unconstitutional.

That applies equally to the 9/11 attacks, to the Israeli-Gaza conflict, to Iranian-supported terrorist acts in Yeman, and to terrorist actions in Iran.

Celebrating terrorism could well be considered a type of "Hate Speech", but in the US, [hate speech is not illegal.](https://www.thefire.org/research-learn/hate-speech-legal) unless it contains a threat or incitement to commit a crime.

Comment: +1. Any reference?

Comment: Sure https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-1/

Comment: Also see the law on "Hate speech":  https://www.thefire.org/research-learn/hate-speech-legal

Comment: I don't think that is correct at all - how does antisemitism and Islamophobia factor into the first amendment rights? We have already seen the Biden administration going after some protestors for antisemitism (for allegedly supporting Hamas terrorist actions against Israel). They same contempt would be invited for supporting and justifying an ISIS terrorist attack against muslims.

Comment: @sfxedit  That is total missing the point!  The question is quite simple.  Is the celebration of terrorist acts iegal in the US.  The answer is yes. Celebrating a terrorist act could well be considered hateful, evil, ridiculous, immoral. It might be utterly condemned by the vast majority of people,  and there is no justification for (for example) allowing it on this website.  but it is **not illegal**.  If you think this is wrong, please explain what US law you think makes it illegal.

Comment: @sfxedit - Someone can *say* pretty much anything they want.  It's not unless it actually becomes an action that it becomes illegal.  That said, it's equally 1st-amendment-based for anyone except the government to refuse to associate with them because of what they say.

Comment: @Bobson I am trying to understand your perspecive - so what was the *action* that prompted the Biden administration to act against pro-palestine or anti-Israeli protestors due to the allegations of antisemitism made against them? As far as I know, most of them only wrote or said something to the public which I think is covered by the 1st amendment according to what most of you are saying.

Comment: The expression of islamophobia and antisemitism are not illegal in the USA. Be sure to understand what this doesn't mean.  It doesn't mean that that the US government is antisemitic.  It doesn't mean that the US government must fund anti-semitic groups.  It doesn't mean that the US government can't be critical of antisemitic views, or favour people that oppose antisemitism. It doesn't mean that if you commit a crime, the fact that you were doing it because of antisemitism is irrelevant.  It just means that the courts can't lock you up for expressing antisemitic views.

Comment: *The statutes forbid communication that is hateful, threatening, or abusive, and targets a person on account of disability, ethnic or national origin, nationality (including citizenship), race, religion, sexual orientation, or skin colour. The penalties for hate speech include fines, imprisonment, or both.* - https://psichologyanswers.com/library/lecture/read/553538-is-hate-speech-illegal-in-the-us - if hate speech is not illegal how can you be fined or imprisoned for it? I acknowledge that the first amendment is strongly protected in the US but that doesn't offer blanket protection.

Comment: @sfxedit - Please share some links about what the administration did against protestors and I'll look into it.  I haven't come across any articles about that, but there's a lot I don't catch as it happens.

Comment: @sfxedit only when the speech includes a threat (of something that is criminal) or an incitement to commit a crime.  You cannot be fined or imprisoned for stating something that is hateful about any of those categories of people, unless there is a threat or incitement to commit crime.

Comment: Generally, I believe that _Freedom_ without any restriction is a paradox.

Comment: @Bobson [Harvard Faces Federal Investigation, Joining These Other Universities—Here’s What Led To It](https://www.forbes.com/sites/brianbushard/2023/11/29/harvard-faces-federal-investigation-joining-these-other-universities-heres-what-led-to-it/). (In my view, it seems like a witch hunt by the Biden administration to introduce a "chilling effect" on the growing anti-war student movements, by deliberately targeting college administrators).

Comment: @JamesK It's not really clear even in the US as this [article highlights](https://undergradlawreview.blog.fordham.edu/first-amendment/hate-speech-its-protection-under-the-first-amendment-and-resisting-it-with-counterspeech/). The court allowed Nazi symbols under first amendment but considered burning crosses as hate speech.

Comment: @sfxedit: Or [banning TikToK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_TikTok_in_the_United_States)?

Comment: @sfxedit No.  Burning crosses is protected free speech...  Placing burning crosses in the front yards of Black families is a **threat** and not protected.

Comment: @sfxedit Oh, I assumed you were talking about direct action against individual protestors. The university investigations are based on [alleged] violations of anti-discrimination laws, which are again about actions taken/encouraged/threatened.  It's definitely part of a pressure campaign, but as long as protests are _all_ that is happening, it's unlikely that any action will be taken against them.  It usually moves beyond just protests, though.

Comment: @Bobson: The First Amendment says _no law that prevents freedom of speech or the press_ so you cannot justify it with other law e.g. _violations of anti-discrimination laws_. Isn't?

Comment: This has gone well beyond discussion of the Question and Answer. Please take any further discussion to [chat]

Comment: @sfxedit - That site (psichology answers???) is not a reliable source for US law, or, I suspect, much of anything, given the misspelling of "psychology" in its domain name. It's a fair bet that much of it was written by LLM bots, and it contradicts itself even on the same page: "The United States does not have hate speech laws" versus "The penalties for hate speech include fines, imprisonment, or both."

Comment: The more one goes down this rabbit hole, the more one wonders what is going on. Its "common psichology" questions and answers all contain the word "adequate" or "adequacy," and almost none have anything to do with psychology.

Comment: @sfxedit because burning crosses were used in ritualized hate-based killings called "lynchings," they *may* actually be seen as threats of violence.  Threats of violence, as well as incitement of violence, are not legal.  So the government can investigate whether hate speech, threats of violence, or incitement of violence has taken place.  It makes sense for the government to keep track of instances of hate speech which can turn violent because, even though they are not illegal by themselves, if they do turn violent, the evidence of hate speech would exacerbate the crimes.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly not, in Canada.

The Canadian criminal code contemplates the offense of "instructing to carry out terrorist activity," which is defined rather broadly:

> Every person who knowingly instructs, directly or indirectly, any
> person to carry out a terrorist activity is guilty of an indictable
> offence and liable to imprisonment for life.
>
> Prosecution: (2) An offence may be committed under subsection (1)
> whether or not (a) the terrorist activity is actually carried out; (b)
> the accused instructs a particular person to carry out the terrorist
> activity; (c) the accused knows the identity of the person whom the
> accused instructs to carry out the terrorist activity; or (d) the
> person whom the accused instructs to carry out the terrorist activity
> knows that it is a terrorist activity. 2001, c. 41, s. 4.

It also has the similar offense of "counselling commission of terrorism."

> (1) Every person who counsels
> another person to commit a terrorism offence without identifying a
> specific terrorism offence is guilty of an indictable offence and is
> liable to imprisonment for a term of not more than five years.
>
> Application: (2) An offence may be committed under subsection (1)
> whether or not a terrorism offence is committed by the person who is
> counselled. 2015, c. 20, s. 16; 2019, c. 13, s. 143.

Unlike the USA, where direct organization or financing of terrorist activity is required to be criminal, in Canada, all that is necessary is advocating for terrorism to be carried out, whether or not a specific action is implied, whether or not a specific person is addressed, and even indirectly. It is conceivable that if the attacks in Iran were adjudicated as terrorism in Canadian courts, even a statement along of the lines of "it is good to kill people who support the Iranian government" could be ruled to fall under these laws.

That said, the fact that the law is broad and could be applied in such a manner does not mean that it would be interpreted that way in the case in question. Most prosecutions that I have found under this law have been in conjunction with more clear material support or participation in terrorist activities, with the offense of counselling commission of terrorism tacked on at the end. Furthermore, given that the people making the statements are themselves Iranian, I suspect that courts would be inclined to give them the benefit of the doubt as to whether their statements actually were encouraging people to commit terrorism against Iranians, whereas the [Atomwaffen Division](https://www.rcmp-grc.gc.ca/en/news/2023/two-ontario-men-arrested-terrorism-charges?wbdisable=true) probably would not.